# Specify/Set width and height on a react-boostrap modal

Tags: size, jsx, react-bootstrap

How can I apply a dynamic width and height to a react-bootstrap modal window?
I have checked the react-bootstrap docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals) but could not figure out how to do that.
Actually the value of width and height props would be dynamic (could be any values) as this will be a reusable component in my app (to be used on many pages) thus can't apply width/height through some CSS class.

'bsSize' property as mentioned in docs also not working, although predefined sizes of xs, md, lg is not what I exactly want, rather I need width and height to be set on modal via props.

Here is my sample JSX code:

```
var MyWindow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return { show: true };
    },
    close() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    },
    open() {
        this.setState({ show: true });
    },
    save() {

    },
    render: function () {

        var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button,
            Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal,
            ModalBody = ReactBootstrap.ModalBody,
            ModalHeader = ReactBootstrap.ModalHeader,
            ModalFooter = ReactBootstrap.ModalFooter,
            ModalTitle = ReactBootstrap.ModalTitle;

        return (
            <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
                <ModalHeader closeButton>
                    <ModalTitle>My Cool Window</ModalTitle>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus</p>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button onClick={this.close}>Cancel</Button>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.save}>Save</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        );

    }
});

React.render(<MyWindow width={700} height={400} />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 35):

According to its [documentation](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals), you have to customize your own css class to achieve the style you want via modal's prop `dialogClassName`.

So we might have `my.jsx` code below:

```
<Modal dialogClassName="my-modal">
</Modal>
```

With `my.css` below:

```
.my-modal {
    width: 90vw    /* Occupy the 90% of the screen width */
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

Then you will have your custmized modal!

Comment: But for that We have to statically define CSS in some CSS file, while in my case width/height will be dynamic via props. So it doesn't solves our problem.

Comment: Well, it's there any possible that we could use JQuery or something else to modify the class's(like `my-modal` here)  style dynamically?

Comment: It can b done but it's an additional effort and React-Bootstrap devs should provide it themselves rather that we implementors pull our sleeves n go for some workaround ourselves.

Comment: @Stephen W - I'm finding that if I set width using the dialogClassName I need to use !important to override the BS modal-dialog style

Comment: Pay attention that if for some modal block "max-width" was specified then the "width" will fits to the max-width value even if you set "!important". You must override the "max-width" value also if any.

Comment: This is only a partial answer, this is not the way to set the height.

Comment: I tried adding a custom className using dialogClassName, but i am getting error saying 

<Modal.Dialog dialogClassName='dialogCustomClass'>

React does not recognize the `dialogClassName` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `dialogclassname` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: Per the comment left by @Cathal I too needed to specify `!important`

Comment: ah yes, chatgpt failed to answer this and good old SO came through :)

Answer (score 4):

.my-modal{
min-width: 50%
}

Works for me!!!

Answer (score 3):

The other mentioned solution only works for setting the width.

For editing the `height`, you need to add your custom css class to the `contentClassName` attribute.

For Example:

```
 <Modal contentClassName="modal-height"></Modal>
```

Css Class:

```
.modal-height {
  height: 70%;
}
```

For editing the `width` you need to add your custom css class to the `dialogClassName` attribute.

For Example:

```
 <Modal dialogClassName="modal-width"></Modal>
```

Css Class:

```
.modal-width {
  width: 70%;
}
```

**Possible Issues:**

Sometimes you will have to use `!important` to over-ride bootstrap imposed CSS, so experiment with that as well.

Credits: Found the solution [here](https://dev.to/itz_giddy/the-right-way-to-resize-reactstrap-s-modal-component-302o).