# React - Fullscreen Modal with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using Modal component from bootstrap for React from [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals), I can easily achieve Modal using the following code,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BaseComponent} from 'BaseComponent';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class InteractiveMap extends BaseComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.state = {showModal: false};
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({showModal: false});
  }

  onFormSubmit(values){
    const data = {...values};

  }

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <div className="map-menuitem" onClick={this.open}>Interactive Map</div>
        <div>
          <Modal className="modal-container"
          show={this.state.showModal}
          onHide={this.close}
          animation={true}
          dialogClassName="custom-map-modal"
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Interactive Map</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
              The body
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button className="button-theme" onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
              <Button className="button-theme button-theme-blue" type="submit">Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>

          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InteractiveMap;
```

In the doc it is written that I can supply my custom css for the Modal, so I did `dialogClassName="custom-map-modal"` where

```
.custom-map-modal{
   width:100%;
}
```

The above don't work either.

I want to achieve full screen Modal here, how can I achieve using the above approach, or if any other approach there to do, but I want to use Bootstrap only.

Comment: Must have something to do with some other styling on your page. I was able to make the example modal you provided a fullscreen modal by adding `width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0` and `height: 100%;` to `modal-content`. Start by looking at the modals parent and work your way up from there until you find which parent is preventing the width from being fullscreen.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Yes I am able to make it work by overriding the default `modal, modal-footer, modal-content, modal-dialog` css classes, but I end up overriding the modals for other pages which I don't want..

Comment: Answer from Qi W worked for me from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624634/specify-set-width-and-height-on-a-react-boostrap-modal/35970205#35970205. Just adding if someone stumbles on this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place the CSS class in the attribute "className" used by JSX to assign CSS attributes to the component.

take a look this example:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn1AnYrAFxOONefi_4N

```
 <Modal className="modal-container custom-map-modal"
      show={this.state.showModal}
      onHide={this.toggleState}
      animation={true}
      >
```

SASS Implementation

```
.custom-map-modal {
   .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, it stills shows the default Modal.. though it is quite straight forward, anything else am I missing?

Comment: Take a look the last update I miss some CSS on the example. Implementing this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432394/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-modal-full-screen